# How to pass variables from Iframe to VF page URL? I'm displaying a vfpage in sidebar as homepage component

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a visualforce page and a controller for it, already written. My requirement is to show the same page as one of the homepage components in the left sidebar, I did that by calling through an iframe, till now all working fine. When any page will get loaded, I want the url of the page not of the visualforce page which I have created. eg.'https://na12.salesforce.com/001/o' or 'https://na12.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp' but not the one like '/apex/mypagename'.

How to achieve this ?

```
<iframe src="/apex/HomePageComponent?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1" id="showskill" frameborder="0" height="100px" width="180px"> </iframe>
```

this is my iframe code, I want something like where I can pass a string, appending it to src probably this way, '/apex/mypage?id='+var

Comment: You can definitely pass parameters to that URL but what type of parameters you want to pass? From where would be getting them?

Comment: parameter would be some what like this '/apex/mypage?id='+var
where var being a javaScript variable, and i would be fetching it from vf page's controller.

Comment: @priyanka, m sorry but ur URLencode didn't work for me:(
thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find the answer with the help of one of my friends, it was simple but really hard to find.

`<iframe src="/apex/HomePageComponent?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1" id="showskill" frameborder="0" height="100px" width="180px"> </iframe>`

I was doing the same stuff earlier also.. just found out something called Frame[0].location which helped me achieve the desired reqmnt.

```
<script> 
    var location = window.location;  
    var static_location = "/apexHomePageComponent?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1&src="; 
    var abs_url = static_location + location; 
    frame[0].location = abs_url; 
</script>
```

Now, from the Vf page's controller i can fetch the value of 'src' quite easily

Thank you so much Vishal for this. :)

Comment: Please select this answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="/apex/HomePageComponent?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1" id="showskill" frameborder="0" height="100px" width="180px"/> 
<script> 
    var location = window.location;  
    var static_location = "/apexHomePageComponent?core.apexpages.devmode.url=1&src="; 
    var abs_url = static_location + location; 
    frame[0].location = abs_url; 
</script>
```